# Provide the dynamic range of values to Sub VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to pass the line column value to the sub that will call a function to calculate some logic.

Before writing a sub I just defined a function and passed values manually to the function and dragging to the columns I needed.

But now I wanted to create something that will auto apply formula to a range of the column.

This is the code I am trying to do, maybe its not the best way but open for suggestions.

```
Function addDiscount(Qty, Price)
'
' addDiscount Macro
' adds Discount to given price and quantity
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
If (Qty >= 10 Or Price >= 200) Then
    addDiscount = 30 * 0.01
Else
    addDiscount = 0
End If    
addDiscount = Application.Round(addDiscount, 2)

End Function

Sub insertAddDiscount()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("F9:F30").Select
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 9 To 30
        Selection.Formula = "=addDIscount($G$i,$E$i)"
        Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a variable `i` inside the formula, you need to take it outside the `"`.

replace your line:

```
Selection.Formula = "=addDIscount($G$i,$E$i)"
```

with:

```
Selection.Formula = "=addDIscount($G" & i & ",$E" & i & ")"
```

**However**, let me suggest a solution, where you don't need to rely on `Select`ing the Range, and later on use `Selection`, but rely on fully qualified `Range` object (this will also shorten your code's run-time).

```
Sub insertAddDiscount()
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 9 To 30
            .Range("F" & i).Formula = "=addDIscount($G" & i & ",$E" & i & ")"
        Next i
        .Range("F9:F30").Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range` call should be preceded by a dot `.` to make it Explicit.

Comment: Thanks Shai Rado, the solution worked.
Just the way I wanted.